# Can the null set be written like $(a,a)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can the null set $\varnothing$ be written as $(a,a)$ for some real number $a$? It does not contain a. It does not contain anything else. So can I represent the null set as an interval like this?

Comment: Yes, $(a,a) = \emptyset$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Classification_of_intervals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(a,a)$ is usually referred to as a *degenerate* interval (since it actually contains no points), and is equivalent to the empty set.  However it would be clearer to write $\emptyset$ for the empty set as this is the more conventional notation.

The use of $(a,a)$ for the empty set normally arises when you are discussing intervals where the end points are chosen depending on other elements of the problem under discussion, and it is polite to note that the interval can degenerate to the empty set (and sometimes important to observe what difference this may make to the analysis).